# Populate data asynchronously from WebService in few dynamically created Div in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, gridview, dynamic, asynchronous

***Problem Summary:***

I have one page having a textbox and a button.
On Clicking button it read few XMLs and get the following data.

- Gets the list of database connectors to connect. A, B, C
- Gets the list of queries linked to each connector. A[0,1,2], B[0], c[0, 1, 2, 4]

Now iterate though each database connector, connect, run each query, fetch data, create dynamic controls and panels and display in this fashion.

> ---A----
>   Gridview A[0] results
>   Gridview A[1] results
>   Gridview A[2] results
>
> ---B---
>   Gridview B[0] results

It works and displays properly if I try synchronously, connecting the connectors one by one. The page freezes for few seconds, but at the end when all operation is complete it displays properly.  Problem happens when any of the connector is down. Example. If A is down then till we get the connector Timeout message, B and C also wait and page loading time increases.

Now there is a business demand that this should run Asynchronously, that means all the connectors should be connected and queried simultaneously like parallel. I tried to implement this by using **WebService**. But in vain. The Div created and closes and then the grid/data is populating. Since the divs are creating dynamically I have no clue how to place the gridviews in those divs.

My current logic is:

```
Loop through Connectors {
 Create <Div class="Container">
 Create <Div class="conLabel">Label</div>

 Loop through Queries for this connector {
   WebSevice _WS = new WebService();
   __WS.GetDataCompleted += new GetDataCompletedEventHandler(__WS_GetDataCompleted);
   __WS.GetDataAsync(Parameters Here);
 }
 Create </Div>
}

void __WS_GetDataCompleted(object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs e) {
  Get result here from e.Result
  Create New gridview and bind to it.      
}
```

It displays like this.

> ---A----
>   ---B---
>
> Gridview A[0] results
>   Gridview A[1] results
>   Gridview A[2] results
>
> Gridview B[0] results

I am not sure if this is the right approach or not. I am very new to WebService. How do i create a gridview in some div which itself is created dynamically.

Can someone help me finding any other approach to solve this problem.

Comment: I think this is best done using Ajax and making calls from the client side, first to fetch the connectors and then to iterate the connectors and fetch the queries etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a ASP.NET Panel instead of creating dynamic literal control as .

```
Loop through Connectors {
 Panel myPanel = new Panel();
 myPanel.ID = "UNIQUEID"; // Using this ID i am identifying the container

 Loop through Queries for this connector {
   WebSevice _WS = new WebService();
   __WS.GetDataCompleted += new GetDataCompletedEventHandler(__WS_GetDataCompleted);
   __WS.GetDataAsync(Parameters Here);
 }
}
```